# Pandas - Look in 2 columns and check each column for a different element, if both columns contain the elements return the value in a different column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame which has 3 columns (called all_names). The first column is called ID, the second column is 'First_names' and the third is 'Last_names' - the data frame has 1 million rows. I have a different data frame (called combos) which has 2 rows: 'First' and 'Last'. (the data frames also have an index column). I need to check the First_names and Last_names column at the same time to see if they contain the combination of first and last in the other data frame.

Currently, I have:

```
all_names['First_names'] = all_names.First_names.astype(str) #setting column to string data type
all_names['Last_names'] = all_names.Last_names.astype(str)
combos['First'] = combos.First.astype(str)
combos['Last'] = combos.Last.astype(str) #setting column to string data type

for index, row in combos.iterrows(): 
    correct_IDS = all_names.loc[all_names.First_names.str.contains(row.First)] & all_names.loc[all_names.Last_names.str.contains(row.Last), 'ID']
    print(correct_tiles)
```

However, this doesn't work and is messy as has to iterate through all rows. any help would be great

The all_names looks like this (when opened in notepad):

```
,ID,First_names,Last_names
0,5231,Harry,Smith
1,2745,Mark,Hammond
```

The combos looks like this (when opened in notepad):

```
,First,Last
0,Liam,Bradnam
1,James,Beckham
```

Comment: Using `iterrows` to iterate through your dataframe will be extremely slow. Look into a means of vectorizing your task to significantly increase performance. My suggestion would be to first create a new column in each dataframe that combines the first name and last name into a single string, then you just have to compare the two individual columns from the two dataframes.

Comment: Using `merge` to solve your problem could be a way, but without some input data (few rows of both dataframes) and the expected output (you want to add a column in combos?) it will be difficult to help you.

Comment: Ok i will look into that, just create a series or list with all the ID's for the names in the combos file, i dont need to add the column to combos @Ben.T

Comment: Can you post an example with actual overlap and a desired output?

Comment: If i had Harry,Smith in all_names and Harry,Smith in combos i would want to put the ID of that row into a list or series.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem can be solved using `merge`. Let's say we have

```
all_names = pd.DataFrame({'First_names':['John','John','Bob','Robert'],
                          'Last_names':['Do','Smith','Do','Smith'],'ID':[1,2,3,4]})
combos = pd.DataFrame({'First':['John','Bob','Robert'],'Last':['Smith','Do','Do']})
```

Then if you use `rename` in the `merge`, with `how='inner'` to keep common couple (First, Last) between both dataframes:

```
combos.merge(all_names.rename(columns={'First_names':'First','Last_names':'Last'}),how='inner')
```

and you get

```
    First   Last   ID
0    John  Smith    2
1     Bob     Do    3
```

Now if you want only a list of ID's, you do

```
list_ID = combos.merge(all_names.rename(columns={'First_names':'First','Last_names':'Last'})
                        ,how='inner')['ID'].tolist()
```

and you have `list_ID` equal to `[2, 3]`

Comment: I keep on getting Memory Error, I'm pretty sure this is an issue with my device not your code

Comment: @HarryMaguire it might be the tolist increasing size quickly, if you are not against having a serie, then remove the `.tolist()`. Or you can replace it by `.values` and get a numpy array which should be less memory :)

Comment: @HarryMaguire I never encountered this situation. I'll try few things on my side if I can help you further with this situation :)

Comment: @HarryMaguire so I pushed a bit the data to 40 millions rows and it worked Then I crashed my computer on the next attempt (silly move to be fair...) Anyway, sorry, I don't know how to help there especially if you are able to have all_names in your memory, the result should be smaller :(

Answer (score 1):

Using Ben.T's idea of merging the columns then doing the check. I'm sure his code works but in my instance, I was getting memory error so I tried this which solved my question:

```
combos['both'] = combos['First'].map(str) + combos['Last']
all_names['both_main'] = all_names['First_names'].map(str) + all_names['Last_names']
both = combos['both'].tolist()
name_IDS = all_names.loc[all_names.both_main.isin(both)]
name_IDS = name_IDS['ID']
```

Answer (score 0):

First create a sample and combine first and last names:

```
l = [[1, 'Harry', 'M.'], [2, 'H.', 'Maguire'], [3, 'chun', 'ior'], [4, 'Harry', 'ior']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['ID', 'First_name', 'Last_name'])
df2 = df1.iloc[0:3, 1:]
df2.columns = ['First', 'Last']

# combine first and last names
df1['Combined'] = df1['First_name'] + df1['Last_name']
df2['Combined'] = df2['First'] + df2['Last']
```

The dataframes look like this:

```
   ID First_name Last_name   Combined
0   1      Harry        M.    HarryM.
1   2         H.   Maguire  H.Maguire
2   3       chun       ior    chunior
3   4      Harry       ior   Harryior
```

and

```
   First     Last   Combined
0  Harry       M.    HarryM.
1     H.  Maguire  H.Maguire
2   chun      ior    chunior
```

Filtering by using `isin()` for the combined name yields:

```
print(df1[df1['Combined'].isin(df2['Combined'])])

   ID First_name Last_name   Combined
0   1      Harry        M.    HarryM.
1   2         H.   Maguire  H.Maguire
2   3       chun       ior    chunior
```

while filtering for any possible combination returns:

```
print(df1[df1['First_name'].isin(df2['First']) & df1['Last_name'].isin(df2['Last'])])

   ID First_name Last_name   Combined
0   1      Harry        M.    HarryM.
1   2         H.   Maguire  H.Maguire
2   3       chun       ior    chunior
3   4      Harry       ior   Harryior
```